# Why is my Unity C# child object with mesh trying to assign to its parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to port a tilemap solution from XNA and Ive based this start of a youtube tutorial but I'm having a hard time with Mesh's (which as far as I can see are the only way to draw a surface).

I have an overarching object TileMap and a Tilemap can have many Map Layers. The problem is inside my code when I assign a mesh to a MapLayer it tries to assign it Up to the TileMap.

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'MeshFilter' attached to the
>   "TileMap" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You
>   probably need to add a MeshFilter to the game object "TileMap". Or
>   your script needs to check if the component is attached before using
>   it.
>
> > MapLayer.BuildMesh (UnityEngine.MeshFilter meshFiler, UnityEngine.MeshRenderer meshRenderer, UnityEngine.MeshCollider meshCollider) (at Assets/MapLayer.cs:79)

Unfortunatly pastebin is down atm but Ill move all this crap off the most as soon as It's back up

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class TileMap : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int size_x = 100;
    public int size_z = 50;
    public float tileSize = 1.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        GetLayer ();
    }   

    void GetLayer ()
    {
        MapLayer m = new MapLayer (GetComponent<MeshFilter> (), 
                                   GetComponent<MeshRenderer> (), 
                                   GetComponent<MeshCollider> (),
                                   size_x, size_z, tileSize);
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]
public class MapLayer
{
    public int size_x;
    public int size_z;
    public float tileSize;

    // Use this for initialization
    public MapLayer (MeshFilter meshFiler, MeshRenderer meshRenderer, MeshCollider     meshCollider,
                     int size_x, int size_z, float tileSize)
    {
        this.size_x = size_x;
        this.size_z = size_z;
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
        BuildMesh (meshFiler, meshRenderer, meshCollider);
    }

    void BuildMesh (MeshFilter meshFiler, MeshRenderer meshRenderer, MeshCollider     meshCollider)
    {

        int numTiles = size_x * size_z;
        int numTris = numTiles * 2;

        int vsize_x = size_x + 1;
        int vsize_z = size_z + 1;
        int numVerts = vsize_x * vsize_z;

        // Generate the mesh data
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[ numVerts ];
        Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[numVerts];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[numVerts];

        int[] triangles = new int[ numTris * 3 ];

        int x, z;
        for (z=0; z < vsize_z; z++) {
            for (x=0; x < vsize_x; x++) {
                vertices [z * vsize_x + x] = new Vector3 (x * tileSize, 0,     z * tileSize);
                normals [z * vsize_x + x] = Vector3.up;
                uv [z * vsize_x + x] = new Vector2 ((float)x / vsize_x,     (float)z / vsize_z);
            }
        }
        Debug.Log ("Done Verts!");

        for (z=0; z < size_z; z++) {
            for (x=0; x < size_x; x++) {
                int squareIndex = z * size_x + x;
                int triOffset = squareIndex * 6;
                triangles [triOffset + 0] = z * vsize_x + x + 0;
                triangles [triOffset + 1] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 0;
                triangles [triOffset + 2] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 1;

                triangles [triOffset + 3] = z * vsize_x + x + 0;
                triangles [triOffset + 4] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 1;
                triangles [triOffset + 5] = z * vsize_x + x + 1;
            }
        }

        Debug.Log ("Done Triangles!");

        // Create a new Mesh and populate with the data
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh ();
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.normals = normals;
        mesh.uv = uv;

        // Assign our mesh to our filter/renderer/collider
        MeshFilter mesh_filter = meshFiler;
        MeshRenderer mesh_renderer = meshRenderer;
        MeshCollider mesh_collider = meshCollider;

        mesh_filter.mesh = mesh;
        mesh_collider.sharedMesh = mesh;
        Debug.Log ("Done Mesh!");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only using 1 GameObject here. You are assigning your script TileMap as a component to a GameObject, then creating an instance of the **class** MapLayer within the TileMap Component, which is on the single GameObject you're using.

I think you should try to utilize the component nature of Unity3D a little more.

To fix this you will need to refactor your code a little:

1. Have MapLayer extend from MonoBehaviour so it can be attached as a component to a GameObject.
2. Refactor TileMap to support multiple MapLayers and spawn the MapLayer as its own GameObject.

I have refactored your classes for you as an example. In Unity Editor you would make the MapLayer gameobjects manually and ensure you attach them as children of the TileMap.

**TileMap:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileMap : MonoBehaviour {

    public int size_x = 100;
    public int size_z = 50;
    public float tileSize = 1.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
    }

    void CreateMapLayer() {
        GameObject mapLayerGO = new GameObject();
        mapLayerGO.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        MapLayer mapLayer = mapLayerGO.AddComponent<MapLayer>();
        mapLayer.Initialize();
    }
}
```

**MapLayer:**

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]
public class MapLayer : MonoBehaviour {
    private TileMap parentTileMap;

    void Start() {
        parentTileMap = transform.parent.GetComponent<TileMap>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    public void Initialize() {
        BuildMesh();
    }

    void BuildMesh() {

        int numTiles = parentTileMap.size_x * parentTileMap.size_z;
        int numTris = numTiles * 2;

        int vsize_x = parentTileMap.size_x + 1;
        int vsize_z = parentTileMap.size_z + 1;
        int numVerts = vsize_x * vsize_z;

        // Generate the mesh data
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[numVerts];
        Vector3[] normals = new Vector3[numVerts];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[numVerts];

        int[] triangles = new int[numTris * 3];

        int x, z;
        for (z = 0; z < vsize_z; z++) {
            for (x = 0; x < vsize_x; x++) {
                vertices[z * vsize_x + x] = new Vector3(x * parentTileMap.tileSize, 0, z * parentTileMap.tileSize);
                normals[z * vsize_x + x] = Vector3.up;
                uv[z * vsize_x + x] = new Vector2((float)x / vsize_x, (float)z / vsize_z);
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Done Verts!");

        for (z = 0; z < parentTileMap.size_z; z++) {
            for (x = 0; x < parentTileMap.size_x; x++) {
                int squareIndex = z * parentTileMap.size_x + x;
                int triOffset = squareIndex * 6;
                triangles[triOffset + 0] = z * vsize_x + x + 0;
                triangles[triOffset + 1] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 0;
                triangles[triOffset + 2] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 1;

                triangles[triOffset + 3] = z * vsize_x + x + 0;
                triangles[triOffset + 4] = z * vsize_x + x + vsize_x + 1;
                triangles[triOffset + 5] = z * vsize_x + x + 1;
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("Done Triangles!");

        // Create a new Mesh and populate with the data
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.normals = normals;
        mesh.uv = uv;

        // Assign our mesh to our filter/renderer/collider
        MeshFilter mesh_filter = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        MeshRenderer mesh_renderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>(); ;
        MeshCollider mesh_collider = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>(); ;

        mesh_filter.mesh = mesh;
        mesh_collider.sharedMesh = mesh;
        Debug.Log("Done Mesh!");

    }

}
```

Comment: see I thought about number 2 but the whole point of having more than one maplayer is the opportunity to have multiple planes each with a unique mesh

Comment: I've made some edits and refactored your classes to suit a more component-based approach. Its just a recommendation to solve your problem, and I hope you understand where I'm headed with it.

Comment: yeah I think I see, so you let map layer know about the parent it comes from and make MapLayer a unity object.